# Adding New Partitions to the Measure group in SSAS

Tags: ssas, cube, partition

I am new to SSAS and got a problem ith adding new partitions to the existing measure group.

I have added a new table to the Data Source View and wanted to add this to my existing measure group as a new partition. When I tried to add new partition this Newly added DSV table is not coming in the list of available tables. Am I missing any relation ship creation at DSV level. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

SSAS expects any single measure group to get all of its data from a single table or view.   So if you have an existing measure group that's already getting data from Table A, SSAS is only going to offer Table A for any additional partitions under that measure group.

You can try using a specific query as the source for your new partition, and you should be able to put any table you want in the query.   Ignore the part where it lists available tables, and just type over the table name in the query.  Be sure that all partitions in the measure group have the exact same columns in the exact same order.   This is absolutely necessary, and is probably the reason why SSAS wants you to use one table per measure group.  Even so, I'm not sure this will work because when you look at the properties of a measure, one property is "Source" which is made of TableName+ColumnName.

But you might want to ask if it makes sense to use separate logical tables for two partitions in the same measure group.  Could they be better separated into two measure groups?   If not, could you UNION the two tables in a view and use the view for the measure group?   This may be what you have to do if the Query suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what helped me was to check every field of both sources for discrepancies in fields type and length.

Once I fixed these discrepancies, my second table was visible in the partition creator too.

In the second source table, I had added additional fields to a new table that were missing compared to the original table. But default `0` or `''` values had different types.
So I used the `CAST` function to do this, ex.

```
CAST(0 as smallint) as newNumber
,CAST('' as nvarchar(20) as newString
```